# RSS Feeds - Sorting and Filtering

Tags: jquery, json, rss, jsonp

http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/alltherage/atom.xml

When I view the RSS feed above in IE9, I automatically get a nice sort and filter interface in the top right of my page.  Firefox doesn't provide this feature.

I'm working on a custom web page that shows RSS feed data, and I'd like to programmatically provide the sort and filter feature so it's available in most (all) browsers.

I've written a simple page using the jQuery $.each method to loop through json and display the data.  What I have so far renders very much like IE and FF, without the sort and filter that I get in IE.  I'm not sure how to approach that sort / filter feature.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling `jquery sort`?

Comment: I'm struggling more with the UI portion. I like the way IE presents the sort/filter in the top right, and keeps it there whenever I scroll.  This is probably more of a HTML element question.  E.g. how can I 'dock' a div or a span in the top right corner of an existing div?  Thanks.

Comment: Positioning is a CSS based issue. Using `position:fixed;` will allow you to ensure an element stays positioned at the coordinates you tell it to, `position:fixed; top:50px;right:0px;` will position an element `50px from the top` and `directly against the right of the viewport`. When a user scrolls, the element stays there.